# asio::buffer type for sending both std::vector and std::string

Tags: c++, string, vector, boost-asio

I'd like to find a single asio::buffer type / constructor that I can use to send both `std::string` and `std::vector` objects via `asynch_send_to`.

Please note that I'm using *standalone* asio, without boost!

Right now the function I'm using to send data is:

```
 void UdpSocket::send_datagram(asio::const_buffer buffer) {
    mSocket.async_send_to(buffer, mEndpoint,
        [this, datagram](const asio::error_code& error, std::size_t bytes_transferred) {
        if (!error) {
            // stuff...
        }
        else{ 
            // other stuff..
        }
    });
  }
```

I'd like to be able to use either:

```
  std::vector mVector;
  send_datagram(asio::buffer(mVector.data(), mVector.size());
```

or

```
  std::string mString = "hello world";
  send_datagram(asio::buffer(mString.data(), mString.length());
```

The above gives me a sequence of errors in `buffer_sequence_adapter.hpp`:

- 'const_iterator': is not a member of 'asio::const_buffer'
- 'begin': is not a member of 'asio::const_buffer'
- 'end': is not a member of 'asio::const_buffer'
- 'iter': undeclared identifier

I'm a bit overwhelmed by the sheer number of buffers and the compatibility between them; can someone help me sort out what is the right type of buffer / constructor to use that can take both `std::vector` and `std::string` types?

thanks!

Comment: Did you miss template parameter in std::vector initialization? And to waht place in the code compiler errors are pointing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accept buffer pointer & length as a parameter, this probably is the most extendable way:

```
 void UdpSocket::send_datagram(const char *buf, size_t len) {
    mSocket.async_send_to(asio::buffer(buf, len), mEndpoint,
        [this, datagram](const asio::error_code& error, std::size_t bytes_transferred) {
```

This enables you to use nearly any storage for this, for convenience you can write simple overload(s) like this:

```
void send_datagram(const std::string &s) { send_datagram(s.c_str(), s.size()); }
void send_datagram(const std::vector<char> &s) { send_datagram(s.data(), s.size()); }
```

But in this snippets you should keep in mind some things:

1. You should keep source buffer alive until async operation completes.
2. Do not copy data/buffers (do not allow data to be free()'d/deleted on scope exit as in your 1st snippet)

Comment: In initial question there is an asio::const_buffer (not boost, btw), it does not own the underlying data, and so is cheap to copy or assign. Actually, that's why you should keep source buffer until async operation completes.